# Is there any documentation available for rviz gui programming in python?

Tags: ros, python, rviz, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to make a gui using rviz in python. The widgets I am creating have an rviz VisualizationFrame in them. There are gui elements there but there is no documentation anywhere that I could find, especially for the apis to these elements.

Anyone knows anyway I could solve this problem, apart from the many dir() calls I am currently making at each step to know all the callable functions?

I am not sure if this should be another question or can be included here, but is there any documentation for writing the config file for rviz(to load from)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58368/is-there-any-documentation-available-for-rviz-gui-programming-in-python?/) by [devesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4103/devesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on what you are doing, [rqt](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt) may be a good solution.

It is designed to handle both Python and C++ plugins. In Groovy, there is an rviz plugin available for rqt.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [devesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4103/devesh/) on 2013-03-17**:
Thanks, joq.
I did consider rqt too but later stuck to pure rviz. But, the main thing I want here is a way for coding using rviz without any documentation.